# Saving values to a nested list after an if statement

Tags: python, arrays, function, loops, nested

```
def main():
    print(style.YELLOW + f'[{datetime.now()}] => getting listing ids[]')
    response = requests.get('api', params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
    
    response_data_ids = response.json()
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(style.GREEN + f'[{datetime.now()}] => got listing ids[status:{response.status_code}]')
    else:
        print(style.RED + f'[{datetime.now()}] => error [{response.status_code}][{response}][auth error]')
        time.sleep(3) #retry delay
        main()
    
    listing_ids = [result['id'] for result in response_data_ids['results']]
    
    my_ids={}
    for i in range(len(listing_ids)):
        response = requests.get(f'API{listing_ids[i]}/pricing', cookies=cookies, headers=headers) 
        response_price = response.json()
        

        
        
    
        price = response_price['priceCents']
        id = response_price['stockItemId']
        item = response_price['product']['name']
        lowest_ask = response_price['currentLowestPrice']

        
        print(style.MAGENTA + f'[{datetime.now()}] => Current Price: {price/100:.2f} | Lowest Price: {lowest_ask/100:.2f} | ID: {id} | Item: {item}')
        
        if price > lowest_ask:
            my_ids[price]=[lowest_ask-100] 
            print(style.WHITE + f'[{datetime.now()}] => over lowest ask[{price/100:.2f}][{id}]')
            prices = price
            ids = id
            #result = zip(ids, prices)
            #print(range(result))
            
        response = requests.get(f'API/{listing_ids[i]}', cookies=cookies, headers=headers) 
        response_status = response.json()
        pending = response_status["status"]
        
        if pending == "reserved":
            print(style.WHITE + f'[{datetime.now()}] => Pending Sold[{price/100:.2f}][{id}]')
    
       
main()
```

So in the `if price > lowest_ask:` loop it prints the items with their corresponding price and ID. Can I have this data saved somehow to a nested list `L = [[id,price],[id,price],[id,price]]` then iterate through this with a for loop to use the `[0]` value in another JSON data and the `[1]` value as well for each list? But I also have to incorperate the `[price]=[lowest_ask-100]` aspect to this equation as well but I think that can be easily done. The printed data works because when ran it will print `[2022-07-03 13:39:24.470939] => over lowest ask[149.00][5789508]` with the [0] being the price(before subtraction function) and [1] being the ID

Comment: Can you provide an example output that matches with what the provided code prints?

Comment: Like what would be printed?

Answer (score 0):

So outside of the for loop you make a list `L= []` , and then inside the if statement:

```py
L+= [[id,lowest_ask-100]]
```

or

```py
L.append([id,lowest_ask-100])
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a list with every value though. It will only print how you have it
ex `[[5789536, 11900]]`

Comment: I am sorry but what do you mean by 'every value'? sorry if im cathcing it wrong, but you said you want every response_price's id and price that pass the condition saved into a new list right?

Comment: Yes, the print function in that bundles them correctly but I also have another requirement `final = [price]=[lowest_ask-100]` which subtracts after the if statement in the final nested list. So for example `L = [[id,final],[id,final],[id,final]]` Because then I want to iterate through every `[0]` and every `[1]`

Comment: Ok then i will edit the answer, i hope its right

Comment: How can I check all were bundled though? When I print it just shows `[[5789536, 11700]]` which is right but im confused

Comment: So what we do is just like append method actually. Basically it will add a new list to the `L` list, so `L` technically a nested list. You can try add a new element with some dummy element if you still confused

Comment: still doesn't work. wouldn't i need a loop to make ti work?

Comment: nevermind im getting somewhere

Comment: Allright congrats

Comment: yep i got it. the issue was i didn't have the list [] outside the for loop but outside the if statement and now im doing [0] and [1] within my new json data thanks